# Compare Arrays javascript with different values

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to compare 2 arrays where first array response is following:

```
response= [
      {    
        organization: {
          id: '75f1e2e1-83eb-484e-bdaf-1da9b57c635d'   
      },
      {    
        organization: {
          id: '810d0465-2917-4d67-802a-69cda41647ad'
        
      }
    ]
```

second array

```
expectedResponse=  

 [
          {      
            organization: {
              id: '810d0465-2917-4d67-802a-69cda41647ad'
            
          },
            organization: {
              id: '75f1e2e1-83eb-484e-bdaf-1da9b57c635d'   
          }  
        ]
```

The function I wrote to compare 2 arrays for assertion is following

```
response.body.forEach(function (index) {      
       expect(response.body[index].organization.id).to.eql(
        expectedResponse[index].organization.id
       );
```

But it is failing with  AssertionError: expected '75f1e2e1-83eb-484e-bdaf-1da9b57c635d' to deeply equal '810d0465-2917-4d67-802a-69cda41647ad'

As the order is different in each arrays for org id's. How can i compare if the order is different to make this assertion pass

Comment: You object is bad formatted

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There are extra (or missing) curly brackets

Comment: If the ordering does not matter have you tried using ".to.deep.include" instead of "to.eql"?

Comment: @AlexSp3 - There are indeed. :-) How could I not see it?

Answer (score 2):

As you've said, since the order is different, you can't do this with a single pass.

You have at least a couple of options, each of which you'd do after checking that the arrays have the same length (since if they don't, they aren't a match for one another):

1. Sort the arrays (copying them first if sorting the originals isn't okay) and then use what you have to compare the results, since then they'll be in the same order.
2. Look for matches in an order-independent fashion, such as:

   - Loop through array A using `findIndex` or `find` to see that array B has each of its values
   - Building a `Set` of the `id` values from array A, and then looping through array B making sure they're all in the set

(Again, in both cases you start by ensuring they have the same length.)

You'll probably also want to ensure that the `id` values are unique.